# Where can I download a list of all plant species of the world?

Tags: botany, database, data

Where can I download a complete list or dataset of every plant species in the world?

Comment: If you download the tree of life 85mb file, it's updated often, although it contains all species of all living things. there are probably resources related to that, and sub sections with the different supergroups and kingdoms.

Answer (score 6):

This website claims to contain all the plant species we know of (and also contains some statistics on the state of their collection). Keep in mind that there are many species that have yet to be found or assessed correctly. The world is a big place.

http://www.theplantlist.org

Comment: A web-crawler may assist in downloading the information for yourself - from this site :)

Comment: web-crawling, web scraping, maybe on kaggle there is a list too :)

Comment: @Andrew Interestingly, there is an option to download either your search result or per-family data in CSV format - for later machine processing

Comment: Fantastic, that is even better.